# Android: Video with variable speed API 23

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-video-player

In API 23 PlaybackParams have been added for MediaPlayer support.

Has anyone had any luck with the `setSpeed` method in `PlaybackParams`? I'm trying to slow down video on MediaPlayer and getting a 100 error (`MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED`):

References:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setPlaybackParams(android.media.PlaybackParams)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/PlaybackParams.html#setSpeed(float)

Comment: Are you sure changing playback speed is causing this? I'm not sure how native media player is handling the playback speed. If the media player sends playback speed as header to the server and it crashes it, then the server does not support variable playback speed. Try buffering it to 100%, turn off connection and try to change playback speed to ensure it is only done locally.

Comment: I doubt `setSpeed` is somehow manipulating my server as you mentioned because I've tried with a local file as well, thinking it was due to a connection issue. Even with a local video file I get the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What do you get with local file?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared Start: " + mPlaybackState + " LeanbackPlaybackState:" + LeanbackPlaybackState.PLAYING );
            if (mPlaybackState == LeanbackPlaybackState.FastForward) {
               mp.setPlaybackParams(new PlaybackParams().setSpeed(3.0f));
                mVideoView.start();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared: if " + mPlaybackState + " LeanbackPlaybackState:" + LeanbackPlaybackState.FastForward);
            }
            else  
            if  (mPlaybackState == LeanbackPlaybackState.PLAYING){
                mp.setPlaybackParams(new PlaybackParams().setSpeed(1.0f));
                mVideoView.start();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared: else " + mPlaybackState + " LeanbackPlaybackState:" +LeanbackPlaybackState.PLAYING);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: This seems to be using the Leanback Library for Android TV and a VideoView.
I'm not using Leanback and I'm using MediaPlayer with a SurfaceView instead of VideoView.
Not sure if it translates well to what I'm trying to do.